# Drawing ZigZags in Java

Tags: java, event-handling, drawing, java-2d

I have a design project and I'm supposed to draw zigzags in Java, using my mouse. First of all, I'm using MouseListener and in mouseClicked method, I gather all the points that the user clicks:

```
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    if(isAbleToDraw){
    corners[points]=e.getPoint();
        points++;
        repaint();
    }
 }
```

Here I use a boolean "isAbleToDraw" to check whether the user clicked "draw" or "stop drawing" buttons.
And then, I draw the zigzags like this:

```
 super.paintComponent(graph);
 Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graph;
 g.drawLine(corners[i].x, corners[i].y, corners[i+1].x, corners[i+1].y);
```

Finally, the problem is, when I clicked on "stop drawing" button after drawing a zigzag, and then after clicking the "draw" button again, it keeps drawing the lines from the last point it left. In other words, I can't draw 2 different seperate zigzags.

Any idea about how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the user to be able to draw more than one zig-zag and see them both on the screen, then you could use a `Collection` of point arrays. Each time the user clicks the "draw" button, you add a new array to the collection and make that new array the *active* array. In your `mouseClicked`, you can add the points that the user clicks to active point array and when you paint the component, rather than just drawing the one zig-zag, iterate through the collection of arrays and draw them all.

Comment: Ok, I created an ArrayList and followed the steps that you wrote and it worked. But, when I pressed to "draw" button, the previous drawing is lost on the screen. Here is how I do it:                                                                                                                     if(e.getSource() == draw){
   Point[] newZigzag = new Point[200];
   (drawing.getMyArrayList()).add(newZigzag);
   drawing.setActiveArray(newZigzag);
   drawing.setAbleToDraw(true);
   
  }

Comment: what are you doing in the `repaint`?

Comment: Well, I sorted it out and its working fine now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Smells like homework.

You're not clearing the array when the user stops drawing. When they click the first point of the new figure the last point of the old figure is still at the end of the array, so your paint function faithfully draws a line between them. If you clear the array when they stop drawing it should behave how you want.

Comment: It is a big project, that is just a small part of it :) Well, you are right. I don't clear the array but when I do it, it won't draw the lines anymore and throw a null pointer exception right?

Comment: The NPE can be avoided by checking whether the array is empty before dereferencing it. Whether the other lines will disappear depends on whether your drawing is cumulative or blanking. @ninesided's answer is a better (although more complicated) solution.